# How to prove or disprove this statement?

Tags: calculus, inequality

For $n\geq1$, $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\theta \sin\theta)^{n+1}d\theta>\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\theta \sin\theta)^{n}d\theta$$ .
It is hard to find $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\theta \sin\theta)^{n}d\theta$ so I have no idea.

Thank you.

I have known that for $0<\theta<a$, where $a\sin a=1$ and $0<a<\pi/2$, we have  $$\int_{0}^{a}(\theta \sin\theta)^{n+1}d\theta<\int_{0}^{a}(\theta \sin\theta)^{n}d\theta$$.

Comment: Not a proof but experimentation with WolframAlpha indicates  that the integral is an  increasing function of $n$. It also gives exact values.

Comment: No proof here either, but have you tried tackling this by induction and using integration by parts?

Comment: I have tried to make it to recurence relation by using by part.

Comment: I am doing the same ... it seems that the inequality holds.

Comment: But I fail. How do you do?

Comment: I haven't proved it ... but I think you can do this using the Lebesgue integral, I don't have much experience on it either.